# Spring Injection in methods with no Class level objects

Tags: spring

How to inject through spring for the below scenario.

```
Class A{

public void doSomeThing(){
 B builder=new B();
 //call other function.
}

}
```

Here i dont want to make B as a class level object.

```
Class A{
 B b;// dont want to bring b here
}
```

nor do i want to use Spring context.getBean("B) or autowire;

So Spring has to inject B in a way that:

```
Class A{

public void doSomeThing(){
 B builder=<injected by Spring>
 //call other function.
}

}
```

So B get created and destroyed with in the scope of doSomeThing() method.

Comment: I think you will need to use: context.getBean("B")

Comment: It condriditics this condition:

Comment: Try to be more specific about your need. If you want to get something from Spring, then you have to either let it inject a value in a class member, or get an entry point to the BeanFactory, be it static or injected itself...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ApplictionContext` to do that

```
Class A{
    @Autowire
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void doSomeThing(){
        B builder=appContext.getBean(B.class);
    }
}
```

If you wants to have different instances of `B` every time you call `appContext.getBean(B.class)` then you need define the bean of `B` as `prototype scoped` bean.

Comment: As this will be a part of Web application. I don want to use any spring context objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

So you probably want something like:

```
class A {
    B b;

    public void doSomething() {
        b.something();
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class B {
    public void something() {
        System.out.println("something");
    }
}
```

and then your XML config will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
  <bean id="a"  class="A">
    <property name="b" ref="b"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="b" class="B"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: I didn't try that in an ide. And you'll still need a class to kick it all off with a main method.

Comment: He did explicitly say he didnt want to do this. Though admittedly we dont know why

Comment: I tried to use MethodInvokingFactory but that requires an abstract Method. I cannot change A to be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by lookup-method in spring. Make a abstract method createB();
and you have make that class also abstract but don't worry spring will  create a concrete proxy object of your abstract class.

```
<bean id="objB" class="com.package.Prototype" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="yourobject" class="com.package.YourClass">
    <lookup-method name="createB" bean="objB" />
</bean>
```

Comment: i have already pointed out what you suggested in the comment below where in cannot make Class A abstract.

Comment: Ok then you can go for **replaced-method** technique in this you won't have to make any changes in  A.class this _[link](http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/spring_method_replacement)_ could help you